# How do Docker Swarm Workers Do Self Check?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I am having trouble checking if a docker swarm worker node has already joined a swarm on Ansible.

```yaml
- name: Check if Worker has already joined
  shell: docker node ls
  register: swarm_status
  ignore_errors: true

- name: Join Swarm
  shell: shell: docker swarm join --token {{ hostvars[groups['leader'][0]]['worker_token']['stdout'] }} {{ hostvars[groups['leader'][0]]['ec2_public_ip']['stdout'] }}:2377
  when: swarm_status.rc != 0
  run_once: true
```

This doesn't work as `swarm_status` will always display error as worker cannot inspect self.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: You can check from a manager node with docker_node_info. Debug the json file to find the information you need:

```yaml
    - name: Docker Node Info
      docker_node_info:
        name: worker
      register: worker_status

    - name: Debug
      debug:
        msg: "{{ worker_status }}"
```

Next, use json query to filter out the results using [jmespath](https://github.com/integr8ly/installation#message-you-need-to-install-jmespath-prior-to-running-json_query-filter-is-shown-when-the-installation-fails)

```yaml
    - name: 
      debug:
        msg: "{{ worker_status | json_query('nodes[*].Spec.Role')}}"
```

Output:

```yaml
worker
```